# how to call overloaded function in the same version of another in c++

Tags: c++, qt

Greetings I have a class with overloaded functions I do not want to re type whole thing again and again so I created function(s) with different parameters see below example and I get compilation errors please help consider below snippet

```
class A {
public:
    inline A();
    inline ~A();    
    QString insert(QString& id, QString& name, QString& email_id, QString& contact_id, QString& reg_num, Address addr, QUrl& urlToLocalFile );
    QString insert(QString& id, QString& name, QString& email_id, QString& contact_id, QString& reg_num, Address addr, QString& pathToLocalFile );
}

inline QString insert(QString& id, QString& name, QString& email_id, QString& contact_id, QString& reg_num, Address addr, QUrl& urlToLocalFile ) {
    this->insert(id, name, email_id, contact_id, reg_num, addr, urlToLocalFile.toLocalFile()); // throws error no matching member function for call to insert
}

inline QString insert(QString& id, QString& name, QString& email_id, QString& contact_id, QString& reg_num, Address addr, QString& pathToLocalFile ) {   
    /*some tasks*/ 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the urlToLocalFile.toLocalFile() return QString type ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be in the **scope** of the class `A` when defining the member functions outside the class. This can be done using `A::` as shown below.

```
class A {
public:
    inline A();
    inline ~A();    
    QString insert(QString& id, QString& name, QString& email_id, QString& contact_id, QString& reg_num, Address addr, QUrl& urlToLocalFile );
    QString insert(QString& id, QString& name, QString& email_id, QString& contact_id, QString& reg_num, Address addr, const QString& pathToLocalFile ); //note the const added for the last parameter
}; //added missing semicolon here

//note the A:: used below
inline QString A::insert(QString& id, QString& name, QString& email_id, QString& contact_id, QString& reg_num, Address addr, QUrl& urlToLocalFile ) {
    this->insert(id, name, email_id, contact_id, reg_num, addr, urlToLocalFile.toLocalFile()); 
}
//note the const added in the last parameter
inline QString A::insert(QString& id, QString& name, QString& email_id, QString& contact_id, QString& reg_num, Address addr, const QString& pathToLocalFile ) { 
    /*some tasks*/ 
}
```

Additionally you're missing a semicolon `;` after class definition.

Also, note that we cannot bind non-const lvalue reference to an rvalue. So the last parameter of the second `insert` member function should be `const QString& pathToLocalFile` instead of `QString& pathToLocalFile`

Comment: still throws error

Comment: @AbdulRauf Does `urlToLocalFile.toLocalFile()` returns `QString`?

Comment: yes it does it is Qt core library

Comment: and does return string

Comment: everthing works just fine except for very this situation

Comment: @AbdulRauf Ok let me see what is wrong. Also i noticed that you've incorporated my answer directly into your edited question. This makes my answer pointless. If you want to add updated code, then just write(add) the updated code at the end of your question and also let the old code there. So that my answer don't get invalidated.

Comment: @AbdulRauf Note you've put the `A::` at the wrong place in your edited code. It should be placed on the left of `insert` and not on the left of `QString`. You can just copy paste that first line from my answer. **For example** it should be `inline QString A::insert` and not `inline A::QString insert`.

Comment: actually I happen to forget including those in the first place and I will upvote your answer as well.

Comment: I am sorry dude I am new to stackoverflow I dont know how to use it yet, forgive me for my bold action of integrating changes directly into question

Comment: Now I cannot change it

Comment: @AbdulRauf Its ok no problem. It happens when we're new. The only thing is that if you were to mention the correct error in your original question like *cannot bind non const lvalue reference to an rvalue* i would have added that `const` part as well.

Comment: thanks may I mention it right away?

Comment: @AbdulRauf I have added `const` in my answer now.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is calling by reference.

Converting `QString&` to `const QString&` gets the job done.
We may not be able to have `string& a = b` and then `string& c = a` to achieve this. We must use pointers or constant type.

That is, of course, according to my understanding and seems to work.

```
class A {
public:
    inline A();
    inline ~A();    
    QString insert(const QString& id, const QString& name, const QString& email_id, const QString& contact_id, const QString& reg_num, Address addr, const QString& pathToLocalFile );
    QString insert( const QString& id, const QString& name, const QString& email_id, const QString& contact_id, const QString& reg_num, Address addr, const QUrl& urlToLocalFile );

};

inline QString A::insert(const QString &id, const QString &name, const QString &email_id, const QString &contact_id, const QString &reg_num, Address addr, const QUrl &urlToLocalFile) {
    return this->insert(id,name,email_id,contact_id,reg_num,addr,urlToLocalFile.toLocalFile());
}
inline QString A::insert(const QString &id, const QString &name, const QString &email_id, const QString &contact_id, const QString &reg_num, Address addr, const QString &pathToLocalFile) {
}
```